# UIImageView only shows image when it's clicked/rotated

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiimageview, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to load image(s) from remote url, after the image has been loaded, I assign it to `UIImageView` on a custom cell inside `UITableViewController`:

```
func loadImage(url: NSURL) {
  self.myImageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
  let queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_USER_INITIATED.value), 0)

  dispatch_async(queue) {
    if let imageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.myImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It runs good, except that `myImageView` does not load the image (I know it's asynchronously loading the image from the remote location), but if I click the cell or rotate the `iphone simulator`, it shows the image. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Add `self.tableView.reloadData()` after this: `self.myImageView?.image = UIImage(data: imageData)`

Comment: A side note: Are you making URL connections? It doesn't seem like it. If not I don't think you need the `dispatch_async`. It shouldn't really matter for your problem but just in case.

Comment: When are you calling the loadImage function?

Comment: Sounds the same as http://stackoverflow.com/a/12209846/629118 setNeedsLayout

Comment: @somtingwong Yes I'm making url connections to get the image(s)
@AndrewM I'm calling the loadImage function immediately inside `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` using
`let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("my-cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCustomCell`

`MyCustomCell` just have `loadImage` method